# How to modify a struct's values based on another function?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a struct, which contains a Vec of f32 :

```rust
struct MyStruct(Vec<f32>);
```

I want to implement 2 functions on `MyStruct` :

1. One that returns a f32 but *needs* to borrow self
2. Another that changes the stored f32 based on the value returned by the first function

```rust
impl MyStruct {
    fn hello(&self) -> f32 {
        0.0  // Just for the example, but the function needs to borrow &self
    }
    
    fn problem(&mut self) {
        for number in &mut self.0 {
            *number = self.hello();
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to change the f32 in the Vec inside MyStruct to the value returned by `hello`.

However, the borrow checker tells me :

```
cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
for number in &mut self.0 {
-----------
|
mutable borrow occurs here
mutable borrow later used here
*number = self.hello();
^^^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

I was expecting it but I don't see any other way to do it.

I tried to not use borrows or mutable variables but it did not work.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: How does `hello()` need to use `self`, does it need access to the `Vec`?

Comment: Yes indeed it is using the Vec to compute the float.

Comment: So the best approach is to use indices in the for loop instead of iterators.

Comment: Oh that's smart ! Thanks a lot, I tested it and it does work, simple solutions are always the best !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, the solution is to index the Vec each time:

```rs
struct MyStruct(Vec<f32>);

impl MyStruct {
    fn hello(&self) -> f32 {
        // Something that uses `self`
        self.0.iter().sum()
    }
    
    fn problem(&mut self) {
        for index in 0..self.0.len() {
            self.0[index] = self.hello();
        }
    }
}
```